# If condition does not work correctly

Tags: java, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I have written this code:

```
    public String[] removeDuplicates(String[] input){

    int i;
    int j;
    int dups = 0;
    int array_length = input.length;
    for(i=0; i < array_length; i++){
        //check whether it occurs more than once
        for(j=0; j < array_length; j++){
            if (input[i] == input[j] && i != j){
                dups++; //set duplicates boolean true
                input[j] = null;  //remove second occurence
            } //if cond
        } // for j
    } // for i
    System.out.println("Category contained " + dups + " duplicates.");
    return input;
}
```

which is supposed to check whether an array of strings contains one or more duplicates.  However, even when I define the array like this:

```
String[] temp = new String[2];
temp[0] = "a";
temp[1] = "a";
```

The if condition is not "triggered". Did I misunderstand how && works? In my opinion, the program should first check whether the two strings are identical (which they are...) and then whether the two indices are the same. If not, it should perform the operations.
However, the programs seems to think otherwise.

Comment: Not directly related, but you could speed this up by initializing j = i, since you obviously don't need to retest the lower strings.  You should also check whether input[i] is null before comparing...

Comment: You can even avoid checking if `i!=j`. You just initialize `j` to be `i+1`. So the second for loop looks like: `for(j=i+1; j < array_length; j++){...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the most common mistakes in Java is to assume that a `String` is an object when its a reference to an object.  When you use `==` you are comparing references, not their contents.  This is why `.equals()` is required to compare their contents.

BTW you can remove duplicates with

```
public static String[] removeDuplicates(String[] input){
    return new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(input)).toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, even more than I asked for :) Perfect

Answer (score 4):

The `==` operator in Java checks if the two objects are the same, not that they are *equal*. Two strings may have identical content, and compare negatively for equality. You need to use `equals` instead:

```
if (i != j && input[i].equals(input[j])){
}
```

If `null` values are allowed among the `input` elements, you need to add a `null` check to your condition to avoid an exception:

```
if (i != j && input[i] != null && input[i].equals(input[j])){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Never** use `==` to check that two objects have the same value. Use `equals()`

`==` will check their memory positions (if both objects are in fact only one), `equals()` is the method that will tell you if both represent the same information.

Answer (score 2):

While working with Strings (and any non-primitive type), remember that == makes a comparation by reference, not by value. Use `equals()` instead.

```
if (input[i].equals(input[j]) && i != j){
    dups++; //set duplicates boolean true
    input[j] = null;  //remove second occurence
} //if cond
```

As a rule of thumb, use == when you want to check if two objects are EXACTLY the same object (you can think of it as if both pointers where referencing the same address).

Comment: @Benedikt Welcome to SO and glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `String.equals` for checking string content. The `==` operator just checks the object reference:

```
if (input[i] != null && input[i].equals(input[j]) && i != j) {
```